# query_vars in home, not loading the "home" page

Tags: homepage, home-url

My wp home is:

```
domainname.com/
```

But if I enable a query_var, like so, in functions.php:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "section";
  return $vars;
}
```

Then:

```
domainname.com/?section=bar
```

Loads the posts archive instead of my custom template for the home page.

Even that `domainname.com/?section_=bar` Does load the homepage...

Any idea how to prevent it?